# Correct __bridge usage with ARC and C++ interop? (how to avoid memory leaks?)

Tags: c++, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a bit of pure C++ code which is reading from Objective-C data structures with the help of a function pointer to a method in an Objective C class. I'm treating the Objective-C class instance to read from as an opaque pointer. For example, the C++ method that does the reading has a signature like this:

```
typedef void(*DataGetterFunc)(void * dataSource, int key, int * outValue);
...
void readData(void * dataSource, DataGetterFunc dataReadingFunc);
```

When I call the C++ method from Objective-C, I do the following:

```
MYDataStructure * objectiveCData;
cppObject->readData((__bridge void*)objectiveCData, DataGetterFuncImpl);
```

Finally, `DataGetterFuncImpl` dereferences the Objective-C class like so:

```
void DataGetterFuncImpl(void * dataSource, int key, int * outValue)
{
    MYDataStructure * objCData = (__bridge MYDataStructure*)dataSource;
    ...
}
```

Originally in `DataGetterFuncImpl` I was using `__bridge_transfer`, but then I was getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS the next time ARC called `retain` on `MYDataStructure`, So I assumed it was being over-released by the use of `__bridge_transfer` and changed it to just `__bridge`.

Are there any memory leaks I should look for by just using `__bridge`, or do I need to use some combination of `__bridge_retain` and `__bridge_transfer` in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using `__bridge` to convert to or from objc, owership is just not affected. That means, that while you're using the object in C++ you must make sure that there's still a strong reference around.

If you, on the other hand, use `__bridge_retain` to convert to void* and `__bridge_transfer` to convert back to `id` (or any other retainable object type), you must make sure that each `__bridge_retain` is matched by exactly one `__bridge_transfer` later.

Comment: so as long as my objects are *not* getting released unexpectedly, I can stick to using __bridge -- thanks!